# Sending email with multiple attachments in php

Tags: php, email, mime

I'm using PHP code that have option for attachment in mail. Everything works great when I have one attachment, but when I have two or more I receive only one of them. Also, I have a problem with echo message when mail is sent, I don't receive any message. Here is the code I use:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

  $to="mares.p@hotmail.com";
  $subject="Online Prijava";
  $from = stripslashes($_POST['ime'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email_adresa']).">";

  if(empty($_POST['ime']) || empty($_POST['email_adresa']))
  {
    $errors .= "\n Greska: nisu uneta sva obavezna polja";
  }

  $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

  $tmp_name = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['tmp_name'];
  $type = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['type'];
  $file_name = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['size'];

  $message = "PODACI U PSU:
\n Razred: " .$_POST['razred']. "
\n Boja: " .$_POST['boja']. "
\n Tip dlake: " .$_POST['tip_dlake']. "
\n Velicina: " .$_POST['velicina']. "
\n Pol: " .$_POST['pol']. "
\n Visina: " .$_POST['visina']. "
\n Tezina: " .$_POST['tezina']. "
\n Ime psa: " .$_POST['ime_psa']. "
\n Broj pedigra: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea']. "
\n Datum rodjenja: " .$_POST['datum_rodjenja']. "
\n Otac: " .$_POST['otac']. "
\n Broj pedigrea oca: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea_oca']. "
\n Majka: " .$_POST['majka']. "
\n Broj pedigra majke: " .$_POST['broj_pedigra_majke']. "
\n Odgajivac: " .$_POST['odgajivac']. "
\n
\nPODACI O VLASNIKU
\n Ime: " .$_POST['ime']. "
\n Adresa: " .$_POST['adresa']. "
\n Grad: " .$_POST['grad']. "
\n Drzava: " .$_POST['drzava']. "
\n Telefon: " .$_POST['telefon']. "
\n Email adresa: " .$_POST['email_adresa'];

  $headers = "From: $from\r\n";

  if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){
      $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
      $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
      fclose($file);
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    }

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $message .= "\n\n\nThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
      $message . "\n\n";

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
      " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
      //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
      //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
      $data . "\n\n" .
      "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
  }

  if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  {
    echo '<div><center><h1>Prijava uspesno poslata.</h1></center></div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div><center><h1>Greska prilikom slanja prijave. Molimo pokusajte ponovo.</h1></center></div>';
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a some problem . i solved it using phpmailer

```
<?php 
require "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 
$mail->Host = 'xx';           
$mail->Username = 'xxxx'; 
$mail->Password = 'xx';
$mail->Port = xxx;
$mail->setFrom('ixx@.123com','ixx@.123com');
$mail->addAddress('ixx@.123com','ixx@.123com');
$mail->AddAttachment("1.jpg"); //Attach a file here
$mail->AddAttachment("2.jpg"); //Attach a file here
$mail->AddAttachment("3.jpg"); //Attach a file here
$mail->AddAttachment("4.jpg"); //Attach a file here
$mail->MsgHTML("<b>Two Attachment. Great Job!.. <br/>"); //Put your body of the message you can place html code here
//send the message, check for errors
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "SENDING";
}
?>
```

You can use external SMTP like mandrill or Google SMTP or you can use your server SMTP .

here is a nice tutorial for phpmailler .

http://www.asif18.com/7/php/send-mails-using-smtp-in-php-by-gmail-server-or-own-domain-server/

Comment: can it be use just for attachments? im not very good with php, most of code is writen by my friend and he's not here atm so im stuck... im not sure i will be able to done it :S

Answer (score 0):

here is code that work

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

$to="mares.p@hotmail.com";
$subject="Online Prijava";
$from = stripslashes($_POST['ime'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email_adresa']).">";

// generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
 $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

// now we'll build the message headers
$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
 "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// here, we'll start the message body.
// this is the text that will be displayed
// in the e-mail
  $message = "PODACI U PSU:
\n Razred: " .$_POST['razred']. "
\n Boja: " .$_POST['boja']. "
\n Tip dlake: " .$_POST['tip_dlake']. "
\n Velicina: " .$_POST['velicina']. "
\n Pol: " .$_POST['pol']. "
\n Visina: " .$_POST['visina']. "
\n Tezina: " .$_POST['tezina']. "
\n Ime psa: " .$_POST['ime_psa']. "
\n Broj pedigra: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea']. "
  \n Datum rodjenja: " .$_POST['datum_rodjenja']. "
\n Otac: " .$_POST['otac']. "
\n Broj pedigrea oca: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea_oca']. "
\n Majka: " .$_POST['majka']. "
\n Broj pedigra majke: " .$_POST['broj_pedigra_majke']. "
\n Odgajivac: " .$_POST['odgajivac']. "
\n
\nPODACI O VLASNIKU
\n Ime: " .$_POST['ime']. "
\n Adresa: " .$_POST['adresa']. "
\n Grad: " .$_POST['grad']. "
\n Drzava: " .$_POST['drzava']. "
\n Telefon: " .$_POST['telefon']. "
\n Email adresa: " .$_POST['email_adresa'];

// next, we'll build the invisible portion of the message body
// note that we insert two dashes in front of the MIME boundary
// when we use it
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message . "\n\n";

// now we'll process our uploaded files
foreach($_FILES as $userfile){
  // store the file information to variables for easier access
  $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
  $type = $userfile['type'];
  $name = $userfile['name'];
  $size = $userfile['size'];

  // if the upload succeded, the file will exist
  if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

     // check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
     if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

        // open the file for a binary read
        $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

        // read the file content into a variable
        $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

        // close the file
        fclose($file);

        // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
     }

     // now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment
     // we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as
     // an attachment, then add the file content.
     // NOTE: we don't set another boundary to indicate that the end of the
     // file has been reached here. we only want one boundary between each file
     // we'll add the final one after the loop finishes.
     $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
        " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
        " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n";
   }
}
// here's our closing mime boundary that indicates the last of the message
$message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
// now we just send the message
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  echo "Message Sent";
else
  echo "Failed to send";}
?>
```